# the trait SliceIndex<[i32]> is not implemented for [RangeFrom<{integer}>; 1]

Tags: rust

I have written a function which takes a generic parameter T with bound `AsRef[i32]`.
Now I want to slice the input further inside my function with `get` method. But rust compiler would not let me use `1..` range to slice. I can use `split_at` method to split the slice. That will work. But my question is why can't I use `array.as_ref().get([1..])` in this case? Do I need to add any other trait bounds to the generic type to make it work? If I do `get` with one index like `array.as_ref().get(0)` that works fine.

Here is my code -

```
fn find<T>(array: T, key: i32) -> Option<usize> 
where 
    T: AsRef<[i32]>,
{
    let arr = array.as_ref().get([1..]);
    println!("slicing successful");
    
    None
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3];
    find(arr, 1);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ffd98655d8ff0fd5c6907e75a8c9821).

Comment: Do you intend to use `get([1..])` and not `get(1..)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing two syntax. The first one is the most commonly used to index a slice:

```rust
let arr = array.as_ref()[1..];
```

This is just syntax sugar for

```rust
let arr = array.as_ref().index(1..);
```

*Note that for the second version to work, you need to have the `std::ops::Index` trait in scope.*

This will not work as is because it returns a slice `[i32]`, and `[i32]: !Sized`. Therefore you need to add a level of indirection:

```rust
let arr = &array.as_ref()[1..];
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7bb4f3a72fa0aefa1b5f1de53ee0d819).

The second possible way is to use the `get` method of slices:

```rust
let arr = array.as_ref().get(1..);
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=febfc8e9371c5df869d9d6d5a9e7ed4f).

Comment: I actually wanted to write `let arr = array.as_ref().get(1..);`. Stupid mistake. I have wasted time over this. 